# Woocommerce product individual popup (shortcode)

Tags: javascript, ajax, woocommerce

I have several Woocommerce products. I need to alter somehow the product button so that when i click on it, it will open a popup with a contact form. How can i add a shortcode to each product separately ?

`data-product_id="?add-to-cart=202" data-product_sku="202"`  - i could use the data-product_id attribute to select each one of them separately with JS but how to use shortcodes with Ajax in Wordpress ?

I tried this method - https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/70u2x4/execute_wordpress_shortcode_in_js/ but with no success . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with PopupMaker plugin https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/